# Как правильно экспортировать класс из динамической библиотеки (*.so) Linux С++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, export, so

Продолжаю изучать программирование под линукс. Хотелось бы спросить совета, как верно прописать экспорт класс из динамической библиотеки в линуксе ? Тестовый проект пишу на C++.

Есть тестовый класс обозначенный :

```
class Book
{
private:
    int m_year;
    std::string m_author;
    std::string m_bookName;

public:

    Book(int year=0, const char* author="Default", const char* bookName="Default"):
        m_year{year},
        m_author{author},
        m_bookName{bookName}
    {
    }

    std::string getStr();

    int getYear();
};
```

Этот класс и будет вынесен в динамическую библиотеку.

Подскажите как правильно его экспортировать что бы он был доступен в проектах использующих данную библиотеку ? В сети много информации по экспорту C функций но не смог найти не чего дельного по экспорту классов под линукс.

Компилирую следующим образом:

```
g++ -shared -o libBook.so -Wall -fPIC Book.h Book.cpp
```

Нашел способ - использование атрибута:

```
__attribute__((visibility("default")))
```

Вроде работает. Есть ли еще какие нибудь пути ? на сколько этот способ верен ?
или же можно вовсе не указывать не какого атрибута ? Все равно программка работает и использует класс Book.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для начала, при сборке elf с помощью gcc в linux все символы видимы по умолчанию, т.е. простой сборки.

```
 g++ -shared -o libBook.so -Wall -fPIC Book.h Book.cpp
```

Уже достаточно, чтобы интерфейс `Book` оказался видимым (экспортированным в терминах MS). Но, конечно, ради чистоты хорошей практикой является ограничивать интерфейс библиотек ([здесь](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) описано почему),

### Как собственно скрыть символы

Для того чтобы gcc скрывал символы по умолчанию нужно явно передать ему ключ [`-fvisibility=hidden`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html#index-fvisibility). А для того чтобы сделать видимыми отдельные символы необходимо пометить их с помощью соответствующего [атрибута](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bvisibility_007d-attribute-2289):

```
class __attribute__((visibility("default"))) Book;
```

или в стиле С++11:

```
class [[gnu::visibility("default")]] Book;
```

Аналогично можно сделать символ явно скрытым:

```
class __attribute__((visibility("hidden"))) BookInternalImp;
```

Применять эти атрибуты к объявлениям вполне достаточно. Указывать их для определения каждой  функции не обязательно. Но можно, например, спрятать отдельные статические члены и функции-члены класса:

```
class [[gnu::visibility("default")]] Book {
private:
  void [[gnu::visibility("hidden")]] doSomeInternalProcessing();
  static BookManager* [[gnu::visibility("hidden")]] internalManager;
}
```

Также можно воспользоваться [прагмой](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Visibility-Pragmas.html#Visibility-Pragmas) с аналогичным эффектом на серию последовательных объявлений (но на отдельные члены классов эти прагмы не подействуют):

```
#pragma GCC visibility push(visibility)
class Book;
class Author;
#pragma GCC visibility pop
```

Есть и другие значения атрибута `visibility`: `protected` и `internal`, но пользы от них не так много и поэтому о них обычно мало-кто помнит (см. подробности в документации).