# Как скрыть служебные функции от пользователя при компиляции библиотеки в си?

Tags: linux, c, компиляция, cmake, библиотеки

Я хочу скомпилировать библиотеку, но скрыть некоторые служебные функции. Я не могу просто засунуть их в .c файлы, потому что эти функции используются в разных модулях библиотеки, но я не хочу чтоб они были видны пользователю. Как это грамотно сделать?

Вот простой, но очень надуманный пример. Есть библиотека из 3 хедеров и 3 исполняемых файлов. В каждом файл реализована одна функция. Одна из этих функций использует в своей реализации две другие, я хочу чтоб видно было только ее.

multiplier.h

```
int multiplication(int a, int b);
```

multiplier.c

```
#include "multiplier.h"

int multiplication(int a, int b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

summator.h

```
int sum(int a, int b);
```

summator.c

```
#include "summator.h"

int sum(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

mult_summ.h

```
#include "multiplier.h"
#include "summator.h"

int mult_sum(int a, int b);
```

mult_summ.c

```
#include "mult_summ.h"

int mult_sum(int a, int b) {
    return sum(multiplication(a, b), sum(a, b));
}
```

Я хочу, чтоб пользователь видел только функцию в файле mult_sum.h, как мне это сделать??
Вот мой cmake файл

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(untitled2 C)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
include_directories(inc)
add_library(math STATIC src/summator.c src/multiplication.c src/mult_summ.c)
```

Comment: Для "честных пользователей". Оставьте в .h файле, в котором описан интерфейс пользователя к библиотеке, только те функции, которые он имеет право вызывать. А со "злобным хакером" бороться вообще не выйдет, пусть что сумеет то и вызывает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Статическая библиотека — это просто архив с объектными файлами, так что полностью спрятать функции, которые используются в других модулях компиляции принципиально не получится.

Из нормальных решений — отдать пользователю только один хедр — `mult_summ.h`. И написать в нём что-то вроде «*если кто-то будет использовать функции из библиотеки, не описанные в данном файле, то мы не ручаемся за последствия, а также можем уволить и/или засудить виновника*».

Кроме того хорошей практикой будет дать какие-либо специфические имена внутренним функциям, дабы не возник конфликт с пользовательскими функциями, например начать имя с подчёркивания (`_`), имени библиотеки и/или добавить какой-нить суффикс, например `_internal_`.

Среди менее рациональных вариантом я бы выделил:

- слить все `*.c` файлы в один и объявить функции которые не должны экспортироваться, как статические.
- заставить компилятор встраивать все функции, которые не должны быть экспортированы

---

Для динамических библиотек можно объявить некоторые символы скрытыми. Для PE-EXE (dll) все символы по умолчанию являются скрытыми, а для ELF это делается [как-то так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925828/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-so-linux-%D0%A1/925869#925869). В `cmake` это будет выглядеть как:

```
add_library(math SHARED src/summator.c src/multiplication.c src/mult_summ.c)
set_target_properties(math PROPERTIES C_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)
```

Comment: Насколько я знаю, есть `__attribute__((visibility("")))`, можно через него прятать функции, структуры, переменные